# Why is stored procedure ReturnValue null in C# when it has value in SQL?

Tags: c#, sql-server, stored-procedures, return-value

I have a stored procedure in SQL server that returns `0` at the end as shown:

```
create procedure myProc
as
begin
    select * from sampleTable

    return 0
end
```

This value is returned as expected when calling the stored procedure from sql:

```
exec @i = myProc
select @i -- value is 0
```

I call the procedure in C# like this:

```
SqlDataReader dr = await CommandObj.ExecuteReaderAsync(CommandBehavior.SequentialAccess, token).ConfigureAwait(false);
```

However, when attempting to read this value in C#, the value of the parameter with `ParemeterDirection.ReturnValue` is null.

[image: param.value is null]

Interestingly, the code above works for procedures that do not select a datatable. Sample code that works:

```
await CommandObj.ExecuteNonQueryAsync(token).ConfigureAwait(false);
```

followed by same code to read the ReturnValue. I would like to specifically use a ReturnValue, not an `out` parameter.

Any ideas?

Comment: If you want a value returned from a stored procedure you should use an output parameter. The return value is used to indicate the status of the execution.

Comment: You need to do `while (reader.NextResult()) { }` and then close the reader first, before trying to retrieve any output or return parameters

Comment: @SeanLange `OUTPUT` still won't solve the problem, which is that the setting of the parameter hasn't happened until the reader stream has finished.

Comment: Thank you @Charlieface, I added `await dr.CloseAsync();` (after my existing code that reads the result) and that solved it! If this question is reopened I'd accept that as the answer.

Comment: The linked post seems to say the same thing.

Comment: It's the same answer to a slightly different question. In my case, `out` parameters were working as expected.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see your other parts of your code, but do you add parameter for the return value before executing the command?

```
SqlParameter returnParam = new SqlParameter();
returnParam.Direction = ParameterDirection.ReturnValue;
command.Parameters.Add(returnParam);
```

Comment: I'm using derived parameters, so this is not the answer. I had neglected to close the DataReader as commented above.